# Trouble with IBOutlet Variable Names

Tags: objective-c, ios, variables, uilabel, iboutlet

I'm having trouble casting a string to exchange for an `IBOutlet` variable name in my code.

I'm trying to reference an instance of an `IBOutlet UILabel` that was declared in the header file by programmatically creating the same variable name later on.

However, when I cast an string to try & substitute for the `IBOutlet UILabel` variable name, the program crashes.

Hopefully, the example below explains what's happening & why needed.  Sorry if the description is a little shaky - I'm a beginner.

When I create `UILabel *tempLabelName` to try & substitute identically for `IBOutlet UILabel *property` (referenced in `propertyUseForNaming` example below) declared in the header file, the program crashes!

```
for (int i = 0; int < 5; i++)
{    

    NSString *tempText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", [aReferenceObject[i] integerToDisplayAsText]];

    UILabel *tempLabelName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [aReferenceObject[i] propertyUseForNaming]];

    [tempLabelName setText: tempText];

}
```

Can someone please help me and explain how I can do this/offer further advice?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific as to what error you get when trying to debug your program. Is this an error while compiling ? A runtime error ? In any case, what does it say ?

Comment: Casting ain't magic, it's just for fooling the compiler. **Do learn C before developing iOS apps.**

Answer (score 2):

UILabel is not a string and vice-versa.

```
UILabel *tempLabelName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [aReferenceObject[i] propertyUseForNaming]];
```

says you are creating a string, and then trying to treat it like a UILabel. This is impossible. You need to have the XIB (or your program) create a UILabel, then you can set the text using the text property:

In your header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;
```

In your code:

```
label.text = [NSString string...];
// OR
[label setText:str];
```

There is a lot more to it (e.g. you also need code in your .m file to implement the property, also need to hook up the xib instance to the outlet), but this is the essence of your misunderstanding.